# Bootstrap table-print not work with showColumnsSearch

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, printing, bootstrap-table

Can plugin bootstrap-table-print and options showColumnsSearch be used together?
IF I uncheck a column in the check-button, in print preview it still remains visible.
Is it possible using the "showColumnsSearch" option to set the "data-print-ignore" to "true" for tagerted column?